# CXF JAXRS client not reusing TCP connections

Tags: rest, tcp, cxf, jax-rs, keep-alive

I'm using the JAX-RS support in CXF 2.2.5 to invoke REST webservices. I'm creating a single org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient instance for each endpoint I need to communicate with (typically one or two endpoints for any given deployment) and re-using this client for each web-service invocation.

The problem I face is that the client is creating new TCP connections to the server for each request, despite using the keep-alive setting. At high traffic levels, this is causing problems. An excerpt from my client code is below.

I'm trying to dig through the CXF source to identify the problem but getting hopelessly lost at present. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
FB

```
ConcurrentMap<String, WebClient> webclients = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, WebClient>();

public void dispatchRequest(MyRequestClass request, String hostAddress) {

    // Fetch or create the web client if we don't already have one for this hostAddress
    // NOTE: WebClient is only thread-safe if not changing the URI or headers between calls!
    //   http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ThreadSafety
    WebClient client = webclients.get(hostAddress);
    if (client == null) {
        String serviceUrl = APP_HTTP_PROTOCOL + "://" + hostAddress + ":" + APP_PORT + "/" + APP_REQUEST_PATH;
        WebClient newClient = WebClient.create(serviceUrl).accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        client = webclients.putIfAbsent(hostAddress, newClient);
        if (client == null) {
            client = newClient;
        } // Else, another thread must have added the client in the meantime - that's fine if so.
    }

    XStream marshaller = MyCollection.getMarshaller();
    String requestXML = marshaller.toXML(request);

    Response response = null;
    try {
        // Send it!
        response = client.post(requestXML);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your sample code you get a JAX-RS Response, which *getEntity()* method will return an *InputStream* by default. Therefore, being CXF not responsible for consuming the stream, this is obviously left open.

If you don't explicitly close that, it would be closed during a Garbage Collection phase.
But even so, under high traffic rates, this little latency prevents the underlying HTTP connection to be reinserted into the internal pool of persistent connections exploited by HttpURLConnection (that CXF is using under the bonnet). So it cannot be reused on time.

If you take care of closing the InputStream, you should not see a large number of TIME_WAIT sockets anymore.

Comment: Thanks agoware, that makes sense. In the interim, I ended up degrading to a basic commons Http connection based approach, since my requests were simple to formulate and I had little need to actually do anything with the response. If I use CXF again though, this will definitely be useful!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely try updating to a newer and supported version of CXF.  There have been a LOT of updates to the JAX-RS stuff in the newer versions of CXF and this issue may already be fixed.

Comment: I would love to, but I'm stuck with this version at present due to some much wider project dependencies outside of my control. :-(

Comment: Dan, I tried the upgrade to 2.4.1 on my development machine but experienced the same problem unfortunately.